# No version specified, and no candidate version available for mysql

Tags: centos, mysql, centos6, yum, repository

I'm trying to install MySQL using Chef on CentOS 6.5. I've got the repositories in place.

```
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  256 Oct 15 16:59 centos-base.repo
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  267 Oct 15 16:59 centos-updates.repo
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  264 Oct 15 16:59 centos-extras.repo
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  237 Oct 21 11:51 remi.repo
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  300 Oct 21 11:52 epel.repo
```

However, when I try to do `yum search mysql`, it **cannot** find the following packages (which is needed to install MySQL):

```
mysql.x86_64 : MySQL client programs and shared libraries
mysql-devel.x86_64 : Files for development of MySQL applications
mysql-server.x86_64 : The MySQL server and related files
```

Running `yum repolist` returns:

```
repo id               repo name                             status
centos-base           CentOS-6.5 - Base                     6,225+142
centos-extras         CentOS-6.5 - Extras                         7+8
centos-updates        CentOS-6.5 - Updates                  1,479+129
epel                  Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux   11,103+36
remi                  remi                                  2,245+30
repolist: 21,059
```

Running `yum list mysql` returns:

```
Error: No matching Packages to list
```

My `remi.repo`:

```
# Generated by Chef for 
# Local modifications will be overwritten.
[remi]
name=remi
mirrorlist=http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/$releasever/remi/mirror
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi
enabled=1
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Did you set up any excludes?

Comment: Nope. All repositories are enabled. `enabled=1`.

Comment: I didn't ask if you enabled the repo. I asked if you had any excludes configured.

Comment: Hi. You're correct. Put it up as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!